# Remove chapter headings in Rmarkdown for PDF reports

Tags: pdf, header, latex, r-markdown, report

I am aware that there are already an infinite number of entries here about the YAML header in rmarkdown. However, I have not yet been able to find an answer to the following question:

I need:

- a PDF
- a title page
- the table of contents starting on the second page
- a page numbering starting at the table of contents
- numbered sections
- no automatic chapter numbering

I would like to do this without LateX code, `bookdown` or the import of any text files.
Except for the last point, this seems to work with `documentclass: report`. Unfortunately I can't get rid of the chapters. Is there no pure rmarkdown YAML header solution for this?

```
---
title: The Force                                                                      
subtitle: May it be with you                                                                    
author: "Obi-Wan Kenobi"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
documentclass: report
---
    
# Introduction
## Sub
### SubSub

# Methods
## Sub
### SubSub
```

Comment: You are using documentclass `report`. That's why you are getting `Chapters`. And `Chapters` can easily be removed using just a few lines of latex code ;)

Comment: Thanks - I know. But without documentclass = report the toc doesn't start on a new page.
So I guess no chance without LateX code?
I'll accept a working solution with minimal LateX code. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10332/261065) from **Tex-StackExchange** to do this.

```
---
title: The Force                                                                      
subtitle: May it be with you                                                                    
author: "Obi-Wan Kenobi"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
documentclass: report
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titlesec}
  - \titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
  - \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
---
    
# Introduction
## Sub
### SubSub

# Methods
## Sub
### SubSub
```

---

[image: "Chapter" removed]

---

Answer (score 1):

If your only reason to use the `report` class is the page break before the table of contents, you could easily add it to the default class `article`:

```
---
title: The Force                                                                      
subtitle: May it be with you                                                                    
author: "Obi-Wan Kenobi"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
header-includes:
  - \pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\clearpage}{}{}
  - \apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\clearpage}{}{}
---
    
# Introduction
## Sub
### SubSub

# Methods
## Sub
### SubSub
```